# curl returns error 111 socket

Tags: php, curl

i got this simple curl code below:

```
$target = "/plugin/api_register.php?name=$activation_name&key=$activation_key&url=$siteurl";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://domain.com'.$target);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $siteurl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        if (empty($output))
        {
           // some kind of an error happened
           die(curl_error($ch));
        } 
        curl_close($ch);
        print_r($output);
```

all i get is socket error: 111
and i cant figure out why it wont connect.pls help

Answer (score 6):

Errno 111 is for connection refused.

There could be several reasons

- No http server running
- TCP queue full
- Firewall blocks your request